# Loading native C library on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, c

I'm trying to load native C library in Android Studio 1.5.1, but get an error. It says,

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for java.lang.String com.example.sampleApp.MainActivity.stringFromJNI() (tried Java_com_example_sampleApp_MainActivity_stringFromJNI and Java_com_example_sampleApp_MainActivity_stringFromJNI__)

MainActivity.java is like;

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("hello");
}

public native String stringFromJNI();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView  tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText(stringFromJNI());
    setContentView(tv);
}
```

Android.mk is like;

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := hello
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hello-jni.c

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Also, hello-jni.c is like;

```
jstring
Java_com_example_sampleApp_MainActivity_stringFromJNI( JNIEnv* env,
                                              jobject thiz )
{
#if defined(__arm__)
  #if defined(__ARM_ARCH_7A__)
    #if defined(__ARM_NEON__)
      #if defined(__ARM_PCS_VFP)
        #define ABI "armeabi-v7a/NEON (hard-float)"
      #else
        #define ABI "armeabi-v7a/NEON"
      #endif
    #else
      #if defined(__ARM_PCS_VFP)
        #define ABI "armeabi-v7a (hard-float)"
      #else
        #define ABI "armeabi-v7a"
      #endif
    #endif
  #else
   #define ABI "armeabi"
  #endif
#elif defined(__i386__)
   #define ABI "x86"
#elif defined(__x86_64__)
   #define ABI "x86_64"
#elif defined(__mips64)  /* mips64el-* toolchain defines __mips__ too */
   #define ABI "mips64"
#elif defined(__mips__)
   #define ABI "mips"
#elif defined(__aarch64__)
   #define ABI "arm64-v8a"
#else
   #define ABI "unknown"
#endif

    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Hello from JNI !  Compiled with ABI " ABI ".");
}
```

Thanks.